# Error :F libc : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 24438 (hwuiTask1), pid 23229

Tags: android

Hii all I am getting error on closing of my application "F libc    : Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE) in tid 24438 (hwuiTask1), pid 23229".
Above is the error. Please anyone can help.

I am using Qt 12.5.9 for development of Application my application runs on android and windows but this error is encountered on android only.
For testing I am using android 10.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sZtmd.png)

Comment: Have you found an answer for it? Apparently it can be caused by the app taking too long to start up on the main UI thread I think - and Android usually crashes shuts down an app if the it takes to long to initialize.

Comment: No I didnt found any solution, but tried giving delay for a thread so the frequency has decreased.

Comment: Thanks Adam I'll try giving more delay, thank you soo much